# Raster Imagery Performance

Tags: raster, imagery, vrt, jpeg-2000

I'm currently building a project that will involve using raster imagery in the field on a Windows tablet with QGIS/Intramaps Roam and haven't been able to get a satisfactory understanding of a few questions about raster imagery.

The data I'm using comes from [MassGIS](http://www.mass.gov/anf/research-and-tech/it-serv-and-support/application-serv/office-of-geographic-information-massgis/datalayers/colororthos2013.html#DistributionandDownload) and is in small tiles in jpeg2000 format. I'm using about 500 tiles. In order to use the data, I need to do two things:

1. Re-project the data to WGS84
2. Mosaic the tiles to form a single seamless image.

There seems to be two ways to do this, one very fast the other very slow. The first is to build a virtual raster tile (vrt) and then use gdalwarp to project to another vrt. Very fast. The second is to build a vrt and then use gdalwarp (or raster project in ArcGIS) to output a new jpeg2000 raster. Very slow.

Since storage space is not really an issue, my question is, which of these will perform better in the field and why? It seems like a vrt that is simply projected from another vrt is more like doing an OTF projection and would thus be slower than a jpeg2000 raster, but I haven't confirmed this anywhere.

If this sounds incredibly dense and there is something better than both these options, please share!